# What is the Authentication flow in Azure Mobile Services? How Social tokens are handled?

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services, amazon-cognito, azure-authentication

Before I worked with Aws Cognito and it is straightforward how the flow works but I am not able to understand the benefit Azure mobile services authentication. I followed [this documentation](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/realworld/) but it confused me even more.
When I use aws with facebook Login.

- user logs in. I fetch the token and user information I pass this
  token to AWS cognito.
- Cognito stores it for me and every time I come
  back to the app, I ask Cognito "hey cognito is my token still alive". Cognito 
  verifies with facbeook. if yes continue, no ask user for authentication 
  again. as described over [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication-flow.html)

  I expect similar behavior with Azure, is it not happening? why in the [link](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/realworld/) tells me that I need to deal with IsExpired myself by extracting token pattern?

And Other question, Azure is using also federated Identities If I understand, on Cognito I can see the users. where are they stored in azure, can I see them somehow or I need to store myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the Authentication flow in Azure Mobile Services? How Social tokens are handled?

1. mobile client requests Azure mobile front ends **(First time)**
2. It will redirect to social platform to login with user custom info.
3. If it is vaild then  identity provider token will be stored in [Azure mobile platform](https://cgillum.tech/2016/03/07/app-service-token-store/)
4. Azure will get the userId or email info from the identity provider token then issue a token with expired time to mobile client and it will be stored in the mobile client.

> where are they stored in azure, can I see them somehow or I need to store myself?

We could get the answer from [App Service Token Store](https://cgillum.tech/2016/03/07/app-service-token-store/). We no need to store it ourselives.

> Internally, all these tokens are stored in your app’s local file storage under **D:/home/data/.auth/tokens.** The tokens themselves are all encrypted in user-specific .json files using app-specific encryption keys and cryptographically signed as per best practice. This is an internal detail that your app code does not need to worry about. Just know that they are secure.

As you mentioned [link](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/realworld/), it is secured and it can be re-used when we can. Based on my experience, it is not security that to store the token in the client never expired.

**References:**

[Architecture of Azure App Service Authentication / Authorization](http://cgillum.tech/2016/02/01/architecture-of-azure-app-service-authentication-authorization/)

[image]

Comment: article about tokens was nice.It made many things clear for me. Just one thing do I have to check expiry on the client side myself or when I request a login, azure returns error that it is expired and i need to call a refresh token without re-signing the user?

Comment: If it is azure stored  provider token expired that needs to re-sign the user again. If the  azure  issue to client token expired but provider token in azure is not expired, when client try to connect to azure , there no need to login but azure will issue a new azure token to client.